# Auto fold code on open file by a certain comment in vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is there any extension available that has the ability to automatically fold possible code fragments like a switch when there is a certain comment in the appropriate line?

Answer (score 0):

I think that one is exactly what you are looking for:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bobmagicii.autofoldyeah

But! I never tried it

Comment: I saw that one and it did absolutely nothing for me... (PHP File)
Maybe I was using it wrong, but with standard settings, it just idled.